# "Knot range too wide" problem when fitting a GAM model

Tags: r, predictive-models, generalized-additive-model

This question may be very basic. I'm fitting a GAM model (for two-class classification) with a few numeric variables. Some of them are like this:

a large portion of values are set at -999, meaning no record, while the rest have meaningful values > 0

As the > 0 part still has some discriminative power, I don't want to drop these variables from the model. However, when I use these variables, my model gives warnings like the following:

`knot range is so wide that there is *no* information about some basis coefficients`

I guess this is because between (-999, 0) there is no knot. Using variables this way can significantly change the smoothing splines of other features and make the fit worse.

What's a good practice in this situation? Should we only fit splines to the > 0 part of these variables?

Answer (score 1):

Consider, instead of encoding missing data by imputing $-999$, instead imputing the mean value of the non-missings in your training data.

Of course, this will affect the fit of the spline.  You should be able to rectify this by introducing a new binary indicator into your model set at $1$ for missing data and $0$ for non-missing data.  Then the model will use the indicator to absorb the missing data signal, and the spline is free to pick up the true trend in the non-missing data.

This is a technique that is quite effective for standard glms, and it does not seem to me that there is anything obstructing its generalization to gams.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is imputing the mean of non-missing data due to it is a reasonable estimate of the missing data? Will your proposal work if I add binary indicator and still impute -999 (as I think it means we cannot measure the value)? Also, do you add interaction terms between the original variable and the binary indicator, or just add the binary indicator as a separate variable? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should be able to add the indicator without the interactions, and still get a good estimate of the spline fit.  I suggested the mean because it is commensurate with the range of your true data, while the -999 is not.  As you point out, the spline is not so happy extrapolating so far away from the true data, and it's almost certainly degrading your fit.  What I'm going for is that the spline fit is informed by only the non-missing data.  This is a pretty well known technique (at least where I work it is) for normal glms.

Comment: That said, i haven't done exactly this thing before, so experimentation with the idea is certainly called for!